# Terraform: How to set an AMI id for a EMR cluster?

Tags: amazon-web-services, emr, terraform

After reviewing [this doc from terraform](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/emr_cluster.html#configurations), there doesn't seem to be a way to specify the ami id to use for each node. I've tried throwing in sensible-but-non-specified options (ami = ?) to no avail. The "configurations" option seems to only provide hooks for modifying hadoop config, not the underlying image. Any help would be appreciated, even if only an authoritative "no, you can't do this with terraform".

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this with Terraform right now.

There is an open [feature request](https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-aws/issues/1223) for it on the AWS provider issue tracker but that's all for now. It might be worth +1ing the feature request or if you're comfortable with it you could raise a pull request.

Comment: Thanks, @ydaetskcoR! I'll be following the progress on the feature request, but I think I have to investigate CloudFormation in the meantime.